# Use ASP.NET Web Forms UserControl in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been tasked with making a prototype web application, and i'm debating between using ASP.NET WebForms or the new ASP.NET MVC.

There is a commerical ASP.NET UserControl that i would like to use that gives me 95% of the functionality i need (and it does it in an AJAX-y fashion).  But i've heard that since ASP.NET MVC doesn't use ViewState, it can't run these WebForms-based controls.

So, is that true or false?

I'd really like to use this commerical UserControl, but i want to use ASP.NET MVC if i can, and only if ASP.NET MVC is not going to give me much trouble when trying to use the WebForms-based control.

Comment: http://www.gleamtech.com/products/filevista-control.asp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Traditional WebForms and MVC aren't mutually exclusive; you could run both of them in the same site. For an explanation of how to make this happen, see this post by [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx).

So you could, for example, create WebForms-based page(s) to leverage the commercial control, and use MVC for everything else. You could also set up a simple test to see if the control can operate without ViewState -- making it OK to use in MVC -- and fall back on the hybrid approach.

Answer (score 0):

It probably won't work. There is no viewstate, postbacks (in the Webforms sense) or page lifecycle which most commercial controls rely on in some fashion.